# Android Login with server integeration

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I am using a login process. In that I have username and password field. Once I login, the username and password will be there even when you exit the app or kill the app.

How can I set like that?

Comment: use preference refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html

Comment: Store your username & password into the sharepreference.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences for this.

Comment: if gave the clear date in app info it will gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android There is functionality of **sharedpreferences** You can save your username and password in shared preferences and check that if **sharedpreferences** are not null then display username and password in textField

Comment: it is not possible to maintain data after clear data because when you did clear data it will delete all data of preferences and database

Comment: No Not any other way still you can manage it from server side

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SharedPreference` as below:

> ```
> SharedPreferences m_sharedPreference=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
>   SharedPreferences.Editor m_editor =m_sharedPreference.edit();
>   m_editor.putString("UserName", m_etUsername.getText().toString());
>   m_editor.putString("Password", m_loetPassword.getText().toString());
>  m_editor.commit();
> ```

Comment: I am sorry what you are trying to say ?

Comment: in setting--> application manager --> click my app it goes to app info-->when i click the clear data button it clear the shard pref values.

Comment: Yes when you do the clear data your shard pref will be removed also.

Comment: shared pref is the only way.any other way way to keep that data.

Comment: No other way dear. You can store it in SQLite database if you want.

Comment: k grishu.some them say if we clear the data means it also clear the SQLite database data.see tha bindal comments.

Comment: @yugesh- Yes, bindal is right if you clear the data at that time your database will gets deleted